# Create Xamarin.UITest for Android Checkbox

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I have an app that uses the Android `CheckBox` control.

How do I create a UITest that detects whether the `CheckBox` is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sample Code

```
bool IsCheckBoxChecked(string textBoxContentDescription)
{
    return (bool)app.Query(x => x.Marked(textBoxContentDescription).Invoke("isChecked"))?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

## Sample App

Here is a sample app that I've put together to demostrate how to do this:
https://github.com/brminnick/AndroidCheckBoxSampleApp

## Explaination

To interact with an Android CheckBox from a UITest, you must use the [Invoke](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Invoke/p/System.String/) method to access the methods in the [native Java Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html). In our `Invoke` statements, we can take advantage of `performClick()` to toggle the CheckBox, `setChecked(boolean checked)` to set the value of the CheckBox, and `isChecked()` to return a bool that is `true` when the CheckBox is checked and `false` when it is unchecked.

In the UITest project, I created a [ToggleCheckBox](https://github.com/brminnick/AndroidCheckBoxSampleApp/blob/master/CheckBoxSampleApp.UITest/Tests.cs#L127) method to toggle an individual CheckBox, a [IsCheckBoxChecked](https://github.com/brminnick/AndroidCheckBoxSampleApp/blob/master/CheckBoxSampleApp.UITest/Tests.cs#L133) method to return the CheckBox current status, and a [SetCheckBox](https://github.com/brminnick/AndroidCheckBoxSampleApp/blob/master/CheckBoxSampleApp.UITest/Tests.cs#L138) method to set the CheckBox status.

All tests were validated via [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud). The test report is viewable [here](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/test/checkboxsampleapp_198eddc7-356c-46db-b88b-7e82ce7af2f6/).

[image]